# Write a command that dynamically calls the argument of another command

Tags: macros

I would like to be able to dynamically call an argument.  The following MWE is merely designed to illustrate what I want and nothing more:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\aecommandA#1#2#3{%%
  \typeout{==> command A ==> arg (1) is ==> #1}%%
  \typeout{==> command A ==> arg (2) is ==> #2}%%
  \typeout{==> command A ==> arg (3) is ==> #3}%%
}

\def\aecommandB#1#2#3{%%
  \aetypeoutarg{==> command B}{1}%%
  \aetypeoutarg{==> command B}{2}%%
  \aetypeoutarg{==> command B}{3}%%
  }
\def\aetypeoutarg#1#2{%%
  \typeout{#1 ==> arg (#2) is ==> \expandafter##2}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Hello:
\aecommandA{A}{B}{C}
\aecommandB{A}{B}{C}

\end{document}
```

I would like `\aecommandA` and `\aecommandB` to produce the same output.  I've tried various things ranging from

```
\expandafter##2
```

as done in the MWE to defining a new commmand

```
\def\grabarg#1{%%
    \ifcase#1\relax\or
      ##1\or
      ##2\or
      ##3\or
      ##4\or
      ##5\or
      ##6\or
      ##7\or
      ##8\or
      ##9\fi}
```

Neither work.  I think I may have tried a few other things, but I don't remember them off the top of my head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you're really trying to achieve; in this example, you would need to have

```
\def\aecommandB#1#2#3{%%
  \aetypeoutarg{==> command B}{1}{#1}%%
  \aetypeoutarg{==> command B}{2}{#2}%%
  \aetypeoutarg{==> command B}{3}{#3}%%
  }
\def\aetypeoutarg#1#2#3{%%
  \typeout{#1 ==> arg (#2) is ==> #3}}
```

which seems to defeat the purpose of the question.

Don't forget that TeX is a macro expansion language; when you write `\aecommandB{A}{B}{C}`, it expands to

```
\aetypeoutarg{==> command B}{1}%%
\aetypeoutarg{==> command B}{2}%%
\aetypeoutarg{==> command B}{3}%%
```

so the arguments that `\aecommandB` gobbled are lost forever. If `\aecommandB` didn't take arguments, it would expand to

```
\aetypeoutarg{==> command B}{1}%%
\aetypeoutarg{==> command B}{2}%%
\aetypeoutarg{==> command B}{3}%%
{A}{B}{C}
```

and the first `\aetypeoutarg` would have no easy way of knowing how many arguments to jump forward to grab the `{A}`. There would be ways to do it, of course, but a better use case would probably be the first step before getting distracted along those lines.

Comment: Sigh. :(  The macro expansion part I'm aware of.  But I was hoping that somehow a macro buried within another macro would have access to the previous macro's arguments, such as when you write `##1`.  Does what you're saying mean, when a command which is not fully expandable is nested within another command, that `##1` would lose any meaning?

Comment: @A.Ellett — that's correct. Your idea is an interesting one but unfortunately it's just not how TeX works.